# In Terminal - For-loop stitching together each consecutive 18 picture to one picture

Tags: bash, loops, terminal, zsh

I have a small script that downloads parts of a huge picture and then tries to stitch them together.

I have, for instance, 234 small pictures, which together would make up one big panorama. How can I write my script (in zsh on macOS) so that it append vertically a set of the consecutive 18 pictures (i. e. picture 1..18, then 19..36, etc.) and then stitch all resulting 12 vertical strips of pictures together to the final output?

This would be the relevant part of my script. The variable `y` would at this time contain the number 234, the total amount of pictures downloaded.

```
#!/bin/bash
((y = 234))
((h = 1)) # set up the counter

for (( z = 1; z <= $y; z+=1 )); do # the for-loop should start with the first picture, going until the maximum amount (here 234) and iterate by one
  convert -append $(ls $z.jpg | sort -V) $h-x.jpg # here the script shall combine vertically 18 pictures to one picture set called 1-x.jpg, subsequently 2-x.jpg, 3-x.jpg etc.
  ((z % 18 != 0)) # after every 18th picture it shall increment the counter
  ((h = h + 1))
done

convert +append $(ls $h-* | sort -V) final.jpg # finally the script shall take all 12 pictures vertically congregated to one final picture by appending them horizontally together
```

The script at the moment does nothing, no stitching nor does it give me any error message.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I've added the `zsh` tag back, as there are *significant* differences between `bash` and `zsh`, and the `zsh` version should be  much simpler. I cannot speak to using `convert`, but `zsh` lets you write `{$z..$((z+17))}.jpg` rather than messing around with `ls` and `sort`. Then the loop just needs to be `for ((z=1; z<=234; z+=18)); do`

Comment: Is `i+=1` in your loop a typo? Is `y` set?

Comment: Yes, `i+=1`is a typo. `y` is set (in parts of the script before). I edited my original post accordingly. Can you, chepner, write an answer so that I can mark it a solution. Do I understand it correct that `z+=18` would jump from picture 1 to picture 18, then picture 36, etc.? What I would like to have is that it combines picture 1..18 together (vertically) and then pictures 19..36, etc. so every consecutive 18 pictures.

Comment: Why are you specifying a Bash interpreter if you later asks about Zsh?

Comment: Because I started to write it in `bash`. Then, macOS switched to `zsh` in the meantime. In your answer, Léa Gris, you can change the shebang.

Comment: Important question: do you think you *must* rewrite your script in `zsh` (you don't), or do you simply *want* to rewrite it?

Comment: You can write your answer in zsh or bash. :) I would like to have a functioning script.